# Are there any general rules or guidelines for creating abbreviations for words?

Tags: abbreviations

**Are there any general rules or guidelines for how to create abbreviations of a word when there isn't any established abbreviations of it already?**

Context: I'm writing an article in which I have to abbreviate the word "questionnaire" (it's going to appear in a figure and have to be cut down to size) and I just don't want to wing it if there actually is a more or less proper way to do it.

Comment: Could you use "survey" instead? It's a shorter word with a similar meaning

Comment: @Waggers I don't think that word would be appropriate since this describes a certain part of an experiment when the subjects were handed questionnaires. It doesn't feel right to put in survey in this case.

Comment: You should *definitely* just drop all the vowels: "qstnnr"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[all-acronyms.com](http://www.all-acronyms.com/QUEST/questionnaire/948126) states that "Quest" can be used as an abbreviation for "Questionnaire".

I have seen this used before, though the word "quest" has an entirely different meaning then questionnaire does, so I generally avoid trying to abbreviate the word so that there is no confusion.

But in the context that you are using it (in a figure), perhaps if you labeled it as "quest." it would be suitable.

When in doubt, spell it out.

As for general rules, Wikipedia has the [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation):

If the original word begins with a capital letter, so should the abbreviation. (ex. Volume =  Vol.) If the original word begins in lowercase, capitalization is not needed.

The use of periods differs between British English and American English.

- In **British English**, according to Hart's Rules, the general rule
  is that abbreviations terminate with a full stop (period), whereas
  contractions do not.
  Doctor (contraction) = Dr
  Professor (abbreviation) = Prof.
  The Reverend (contraction or abbreviation) = Revd or Rev.
  The Right Honourable (contraction and abbreviation) = Rt Hon.
- In **American English**, the period is usually added if the
  abbreviation might otherwise be interpreted as a word, but some
  American writers choose not to use one.

To form the plural of an abbreviation, a number, or a capital letter used as a noun, simply add a lowercase s to the end. (ex. Mind your Ps and Qs.)

To indicate the plural of the abbreviation of a unit of measure, the same form is used as in the singular. (ex. 1 min or 20 min.)

Comment: This pretty much solves my problem, but I guess it isn't an answer to my main question about general rules or guidelines.

Comment: I found some rules and guidelines which I included above. Hope they help.

Comment: Historical usage used to add apostrophes with uppercase letters as well.  As and Is can easily be mistaken for words if they are not.