# What's "NAmE" abbreviated from in "Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary"?

Tags: abbreviations

The "N" in "NAmE" confuses me very much.

Comment: North American English comes to mind

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to search the answer, but "NAmE" is the same to "name" for Google.

Comment: Yes, I was about to complain that this is 'general reference', then hit this problem. As the abbreviation doesn't appear in ['AcronymFinder'](http://www.acronymattic.com/NAME.html), it must be in-house, which surprises me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in another question: ***North American English***

[Why some abbreviations ended with a period, but some not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/why-some-abbreviations-ended-with-a-period-but-some-not)

[image]

Comment: NAmE/North American English here is probably an inclusive term for Canadian and American English. At least that's the definition on WIKI. The odd term here is US instead of the standard AmE/AmericanEnglish; maybe the compilers thought it would be unlogical for American to be a subset of North American.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing...