# What is the right way of abbreviating expressions like "A of B"?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations

Would it be...

> 1. AOB
> 2. AoB
> 3. AB

or something else?

e.g. "Centre of Gravity" --> [COG/CoG/CG]

Comment: All the three forms are in use -- various factors (including the inventor's whim) determine the choice.

Comment: General rules or guidelines for how to create abbreviations (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38408/are-there-any-general-rules-or-guidelines-for-creating-abbreviations-for-words)

Comment: center of gravity is usually cg

Answer (score 2):

I would use the third one :

> 3. **AB**

Like in USA, we do not abbreviate prepositions or pronouns.

---

The main reason to write *"AoB"* or *"AOB"* is to **disambiguate** with an already existing meaning. Using @Glorfindel example, *"Proof of concept"* cannot be abbreviated as *"PC"* because *PC* is already a well known abbreviation.

---

The list of abbreviations of [CG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CG) refers to [Center of Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CG#Science_and_mathematics) in Science and mathematics section.

Comment: You're right, however there are some exceptions, for example **AFJ** (Alliance for Justice) and **AFLM** (Advocates for Life Ministries).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation, here are some examples:

- MOAB: Mother of all bombs (though this is probably a [Backronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym))
- PoC: Proof of concept
- USA: United States of America (thanks @Yohann)